# Image name variable does not work at all stages in Jenkins declarative pipeline

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

My issue is that im trying to configure a Jenkins job using the declarative pipeline script and with that im facing some issue with the variable call.

For Example:

```
 pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
        JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.11.0.9-1.el7_9.x86_64"
        M2_HOME="/opt/tools/maven"
        PATH="${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${M2_HOME}/bin:$PATH"
        IMAGE_NAME = "us.gcr.io/myproject/myimage"
```

Here, i'm using IMAGE_NAME variable, so i can call this variable at different stages in the script. Below you will see the part of the script

```
stage('Build DockerImage for Pathla Backend') {
            steps {
                
                echo "Build DockerImage of Pathla Backend"
                
                sh '''        
                   
                    d=`date +%Y%m%d%H%M`
                    build_version=${d}-v${BUILD_NUMBER}
                    pwd
                    cd mlp
                    cd pathla/pathla-service
                    cp -r /etc/mlp/./*.pem  src/main/resources/METINF/resources/
                    mvn -e clean install -DskipTests=true -Dquarkus.container-image.build=true
                    IMAGE_PATH="${IMAGE_NAME}:${build_version}"
                    docker tag us.gcr.io/myproject/myimage $IMAGE_PATH
                    echo "Docker image to Push:: $IMAGE_PATH"
                    echo "Once pushed run this command:: docker rmi $IMAGE_PATH"
                    " 

                '''
            }
        }
```

Now if you see this "IMAGE_PATH="${IMAGE_NAME}:${build_version}" line in the above script, we are using the IMAGE_PATH as 1 variable (to provide image name)  and build_version (to provide build version to the image)

we are calling the same variable (IMAGE_PATH) in the below script to scan the image using the PRISMA Cloud Scanner, but it doesn't work.

```
"stage('Scan via PrismaCloud for vulnerabilities of Pathla Backend') {
          steps {
            script {
               withCredentials([
               usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'mycluster',
                usernameVariable: 'username',
                passwordVariable: 'password')
                ])  
              
           {
            sh '''
                   
                   imagename=${IMAGE_PATH}
                   /opt/mlp/twistcli images scan -u $username -p $password --details --address https://10.XXX.XXX.XXX:8083 ${imagename}
> /bdnfs/pipelines/scan-out-details-backend.txt
```

if you check the above variable "${imagename}" it should call the "IMAGE_PATH" variable but it is not calling it and are not getting the results. And also, when i build this job and run it, i get the below error from the logs:

```
+ imagename=
+ /opt/mlp/twistcli images scan -u **** -p **** --details --address https://10.XXX.XXX.XXX:8083
**"missing image ID"**
```

I want this image `us.gcr.io/myproject/myimage` to be converted into the variable and then we call this variable at any stage of this pipeline script.

Comment: I don't recommend making any requests for us to do anything ASAP. If it has any affect, it's the opposite what you want to achieve.

Comment: You can't  reuse variable in a shell that was set in another shell... Create IMAGE_PATH var inside environment block...

Comment: @daggett i tried creating the IMAGE_PATH inside the environment block but problem is that im only getting the image name "us.gcr.io/big-data-poc-216405/pathla-service-prod" and the image should come along with the date and the Version attached to it.

Something lie this:
"us.gcr.io/big-data-poc-216405/pathshala-service-prod:$build_version"

Comment: Can anyone help me with this issue plz.

Comment: You're setting `IMAGE_PATH` in one of the `sh` scripts and then, on a different stage, trying to refer to that... that will probably never work. If you want the `sh` script to "communicate" with another one that runs after it, maybe store the variable on a file, then read from it.